# How can I handle the element locator selection type(xpath or tag or id or class) changing frequently using Selenium?

Tags: selenium

In my application during releases, I'm forced to change `id` to `xpath` or `class` name or tag. So I can't use any of the element selection methods like `driver.findElement(By.id())`.

In the next build I might have to use `driver.findElement(By.xpath())`  OR `driver.findElement(By.name())` for the same element location. This means I will have to visit each and every class file I have written and modify `By.id()` to the respective selector.

Is there any way to avoid this by parametrising or some other way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue so came up with this generic method

```
 public WebElement getElement(Identifier identifier, String expression) {
        By byElement = null;
        switch (identifier) {
        case xpath: {
            byElement = By.xpath(expression);
            break;
        }
        case id: {
            byElement = By.id(expression);
            break;
        }
        case name: {
            byElement = By.name(expression);
            break;
        }
        case classname: {
            byElement = By.className(expression);
            break;
        }
        case linktext: {
            byElement = By.linkText(expression);
            break;
        }
        case paritallinktext: {
            byElement = By.partialLinkText(expression);
            break;
        }
        case tagname: {
            byElement = By.tagName(expression);
            break;
        }
        }
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(byElement);
        return element;
    }

 public static enum Identifier {
        xpath, id, name, classname, paritallinktext, linktext, tagname
    };
```

You can also use properties file to store values. Like

```
# login
login.username.identifier=xpath
login.username.expression=//input[@id='userNameText']
```

and in Java you can write

```
SeleniumUtil.getElement(prop.getProperty("login.username.identifier"), prop.getProperty("login.username.expression")).click();
```

So you will not need to change any Java code

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of key=value in your locators as a good practice which was seen in Selenium 1.0 and accordingly the selector will be selected.

So you can have a common getByLocator method that returns you with the By class object, example code

```
public By getByLocator(String locator) {
    By by = null;
    if (locator.startsWith("class=")) {
        by = By.className(locator.replace("class=", "").trim());
    } else if (locator.startsWith("css=")) {
        by = By.cssSelector(locator.replace("css=","").trim());         
    } else if (locator.startsWith("link=")) {
        by = By.linkText(locator.replace("link=", "").trim());
    } else if (locator.startsWith("//") or locator.startsWith("/")) {
        by = By.xpath(locator);
    } else if (locator.startsWith("id=")) {
        by = By.id(locator.replace("id=", ""));
    } else {
        by = By.name(locator.replace("name=", ""));
    }
    return by;
}
```

Here I made use of link=, css=, id= as some of factors to identify the locator type and accordingly I got the By locator object.

The usage of this would be something like below

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(getByLocator("css= input[type=input]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work on your framework. Make it more generic. My code handles the problem. I have used key and value concept. In my .properties file, I have defind the object like

```
Test_login_user=id||username
Test_login_pass=className||passwd
```

after that my code get the value and spits it from ||. Here I have mention the type of locator if its BY id then id||username etc.

```
public By extractWebElement(String keyobject){
    if(keyobject.startsWith("name_")){
        currentWebElement = By.name(actualLocator);
    }else if(keyobject.startsWith("xpath_")){
        currentWebElement =By.xpath(actualLocator);
    }else if(keyobject.startsWith("linkText_")){
        currentWebElement =By.linkText(actualLocator);
    }else if(keyobject.startsWith("id_")){
        currentWebElement =By.id(actualLocator);
    }else if(keyobject.startsWith("cssSelector_")){
        currentWebElement =By.cssSelector(actualLocator);
    }else if(keyobject.startsWith("tagName_")){
        currentWebElement =By.tagName(actualLocator);
    }
    return currentWebElement;
}
public String extractActualLocator(String locatorInSheet ){
    int underScoreIndex = locatorInSheet.indexOf('_');
    return locatorInSheet.substring(underScoreIndex+1);
}
```

Now actual locator is in the "currentWebElement", we can use this in our methods. See how my keywords are written

```
public  String enterTextt(By object,String data){
    APP_LOGS.debug("Writing in text box");
    try{
        ***driver.findElement(object).sendKeys(data);***
    }catch(Exception e){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+" Unable to write "+e.getMessage();
    }
    return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
}
```